# NPOI SetCellValue method Not able to update cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stream, filestream, hssfworkbook

check below code

```
     {
            var file = Request.Form.Files;
            var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "dowanloadErpFiles");
            var newFileName = $"EeasergyFile_{DateTime.Now.ToPersianDateTime().Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_")}.xls";

            newFilePath = Path.Combine(path, newFileName);

            List<string> FirstColumn_Value = new List<string>();

            Stream sr = System.IO.Stream.Null;
            HSSFWorkbook hssfwb = null;
            HSSFSheet SettingSheet = null;
            HSSFSheet RelaySheet = null;
            HSSFRow dataRow;
            int countRow = 0;
            string cel = "";
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (file.Count > 0)
                {
                    using (sr = file[0].OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(sr);
                        sr.Close();
                         SettingSheet =(HSSFSheet) hssfwb.GetSheet("Settings");
                         RelaySheet = (HSSFSheet)hssfwb.GetSheet("Relay");
                         countRow = SettingSheet.PhysicalNumberOfRows;

                        for (int i = 0; i < countRow; i++)
                        {
                            cel = SettingSheet.GetRow(i).Cells[0].StringCellValue;

                            FirstColumn_Value.Add(cel);
                        }
                        foreach (var row in lst)
                        {
                            string SQL_Address = row.ADDRESS;
                            string ParamValue = row.PARAMETER_VALUE;


                            for (int y = 0; y < FirstColumn_Value.Count; y++)
                            {
                                if (SQL_Address == FirstColumn_Value[y])
                                {
                                    dataRow = (HSSFRow)SettingSheet.GetRow(y);
                                   dataRow.GetCell(2).SetCellValue(ParamValue);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        hssfwb.Write(fs);
                        fs.Close();
                    }

                }


            });
```

}

Comment: When I give the value constant to **ParamValue**, the program has no problem and the file gets edited .
for example   ParamValue="mystring"

Comment: What is the defination and value for `lst`? It seems to be related with sharing data between threads, share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TaoZhou My problem was fixed,Tnx